# Tkinter: Label, canvas e imágenes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy experimentando con tkinter y decidí hacer un ajedrez sencillos para comprender mejor como funciona, pero tengo un problema: no consigo solucionar ni encontrar la solución en internet(probablemente esté buscando mal) pero en fin, tengo este código:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Aplicacion:
    def __init__(self):

        w=75
        h=75
        ygrid = 0
        xblack = 0

        self.window=tk.Tk()
        self.window.title('Ajedrez')
        self.window.resizable(0,0)
        self.window.geometry('600x600')
        self.lienzo=tk.Canvas(self.window, width=600, height=600, background="pale goldenrod")
        self.lienzo.grid(column=0, row=0)

        for j in range(8):
            for i in range(4):
                casilla = tk.Label(self.lienzo, padx=10, pady=5, bg='saddle brown')
                casilla.place(x=xblack, y=ygrid, width=w, height=h)
                xblack += 150
            if xblack == 600:
                xblack = 75
            else:
                xblack = 0
            ygrid += 75 

        archi1=tk.PhotoImage(file="peon.png")
        self.lienzo.create_image(30, 40, image=archi1, anchor="nw", tags="movil")
        archi2=tk.PhotoImage(file="peon.png")
        self.lienzo.create_image(30, 80, image=archi2, anchor="nw", tags="movil")
        self.lienzo.tag_bind("movil", "<ButtonPress-1>", self.presion_boton)
        self.lienzo.tag_bind("movil", "<Button1-Motion>", self.mover)
        self.pieza_seleccionada = None
        self.window.mainloop()


    def presion_boton(self, evento):
        carta = self.lienzo.find_withtag(tk.CURRENT)
        self.pieza_seleccionada = (carta, evento.x, evento.y)

    def mover(self, evento):
        x, y = evento.x, evento.y
        carta, x1, y1 = self.pieza_seleccionada
        self.lienzo.move(carta, x - x1, y - y1)
        self.pieza_seleccionada = (carta, x, y)    

aplicacion1=Aplicacion()
```

Básicamente creo un tablero y dos peones pero como se puede ver al ejecutar el código un peón queda debajo de una casilla, cosa que obviamente se repite al mover los peones.

Me gustaría que al mover los peones se visualizaran por delate de las casillas ¿Alguna solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica que en tu tablero estas utilizando un widget LABEL para construirlo

```
casilla = tk.Label(self.lienzo, padx=10, pady=5, bg='saddle brown')
```

Pero en tu imagen estas utilizando un canvas para pintarlo , por tanto el widget `LABEL`  tendrá prioridad sobre tu lienzo

```
self.lienzo.create_image(30, 40, image=archi1, anchor="nw", tags="movil")
```

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar Widget `LABEL` para pintar tu peón así este no aparecerá de bajo sino por encima de tu tablero.

```
tk.Label(image = archi1).place(x=120, y=80, width=25, height=25, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.4
```

O  viceversa, también puedes utilizar utilizar el `Canvas` para formar tu tablero y no así un widget `Label`

Por ejemplo:
`self.lienzo.create_rectangle(0, 0, x, y, fill='black')` introduciéndolo en un `for in`

Comment: Me gusta esa solución, había intentado con todos los widgets menos con canvas. ¿hay manera de forzar a tkinter para darle prioridad a un widget en especifico?

Comment: @Mauricio La única forma de darle prioridad es la declaración de tus lienzos, si quieres que el lienzo 1 vaya por debajo lo declaras primero, o si quieres que vaya encima lo declaras  después, y utilizas el repintado para volverlos a visualizar cuando se realice algún movimiento sobre ellos.

Comment: Gracias gracias, lo que preguntaba era si había forma de forzar que un Canvas se visualizara por encima de un Label, por ejemplo, pero supongo que no sé puede o no es tan sencillo como yo pensaba, aun así, me sirvió absolutamente todo lo que me dijiste.